# Apache camel using seda

Tags: asynchronous, apache-camel

I want to have a behavior like this:
Camel reads a file from a directory, splits it into chunks (using streaming), sends each chunk to a seda queue for concurrent processing, and after the processing is done, a report generator is invoked.
This is my camel route:

```
from("file://c:/mydir?move=.done")
.to("bean:firstBean")
.split(ExpressionBuilder.beanExpression("splitterBean", "split"))
.streaming()
.to("seda:processIt")
.end()
.to("bean:reportGenerator");

from("seda:processIt")
.to("bean:firstProcessingBean")
.to("bean:secondProcessingBean");
```

When I run this, the reportGenerator bean is run concurrently with the seda processing.
How to make it run once after the whole seda processing is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The splitter has built-in parallel so you can do this easier as follows:

```
from("file://c:/mydir?move=.done")
  .to("bean:firstBean")
  .split(ExpressionBuilder.beanExpression("splitterBean", "split"))
  .streaming().parallelProcessing()
    .to("bean:firstProcessingBean")
    .to("bean:secondProcessingBean");
  .end()
  .to("bean:reportGenerator");
```

You can see more details about the parallel option at the Camel splitter page: http://camel.apache.org/splitter

Comment: That works quite good, but is there a way to use seda component to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the delayer pattern of Camel on the second route to achieve the purpose.

delay(long) in which the argument indicates time in milliseconds. [You can read more abuout this pattern here](http://camel.apache.org/delayer.html)

For eg; `from("seda:processIt").delay(2000)
.to("bean:firstProcessingBean");` //delays this route by 2 seconds

I'd suggest the usage of **startupOrder** to configure the startup of route though.
The official documentation provides good details on the topic. [Kindly read it here](http://camel.apache.org/configuring-route-startup-ordering-and-autostartup.html)

Point to note -  "  The routes with the lowest startupOrder is started first. All startupOrder defined must be unique among all routes in your CamelContext."

So, I'd suggest something like this -

```
from("endpoint1").startupOrder(1)
.to("endpoint2");


from("endpoint2").startupOrder(2)
.to("endpoint3");
```

Hope that helps..

PS : I'm new to Apache Camel and to stackoverflow as well. Kindly pardon any mistake that might've occured.

Comment: I can't use delay, because I don't know how long the seda processing will take. Specifying startup order also won't work here, because the second route (from("seda:...) is started by the first route.

Comment: Claus's solution works fine in your case. :) This kind of synchronization often crops up while using camel routes and even I'm still learning more techniques as I go. As of now, I use the direct component more than anything to work as synch triggers.